# Firebase server login with node.js: databaseAuthVariableOverride "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: node.js, server, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following the guide to [login a Server with limited privileges into Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). My code looks like:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "myJsonFile.json",
  databaseURL: "https://myAppAddress.firebaseio.com/"
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "server"
  }
});
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

I am quite new to node.js and it is my first time trying to run a server. I have managed to run it with unlimited privileges, but when adding `databaseAuthVariableOverride` it crashes with the error above.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just forgot a comma.

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "myJsonFile.json",
  databaseURL: "https://myAppAddress.firebaseio.com/",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "server"
  }
});
```

Comment: That is completely right! Thank you very much for your feedback. I cannot believe I wrote the code with the same mistake at least 3 times. Now it is fixed! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just catch it easily thanks to this error message : ´SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier´

Comment: Good to know for the next time. Thank you for this tip!